# Did the ancient Egyptians really know that meteorite iron came from meteorites?

Tags: ancient-egypt, metallurgy

A dagger from Tutankhamun's tomb was probably made of meteorite iron.

Quote translated from German from a newspaper article:

> "Researchers assume, based on hieroglyphics that apparently described meteorites, that the Ancient Egyptians were "aware that these rare pieces of iron fell from the sky"" *[Welt.de:Dagger in Tutankhamun's burial chamber probably made of meteorite iron](https://www.welt.de/newsticker/dpa_nt/infoline_nt/wissenschaft_nt/article156019367/Dolch-in-Tutanchamun-Grabkammer-wohl-aus-Meteorit-Eisen.html)*

According to [German-language Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisen), the word for this material was "bj-n-pt", which supposedly meant "iron of the sky".

But how could the Egyptians know that the lumps actually fell "from the sky"?

Comment: ? Observation? They saw an object fall from the sky, investigated the impact crater and found iron?  Iron they didn't mine/smelt?  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous_metallurgy), "Meteoric iron, a characteristic iron–nickel alloy, was used by various ancient peoples thousands of years before the Iron Age. Such iron, being in its native metallic state, required no smelting of ores.[5][6]".  I doubt they had a theory of "meteorites", but they understood things that fell from the sky,

Comment: @MCW: Additionally: they would have seen the brightness of the falling object, it being a meteor; and meteorites are quite warm, if not downright hot, for some time after landing. OP should note that the fact of living thousands of years ago doesn't justify an assumption of being of lesser intelligence than us.

Comment: @Siegfried, can you confirm/deny whether this answers the question?

Comment: My reasoning was that meteoric iron can be found everywhere in nature, but the impact of a meteor is only very rarely observed. Since 1900, only about 6 meteorite impacts per year have been observed worldwide in which material is also found. But of course, such an observation could also be made by the ancient Egyptians. The following questions remain:
Do the records actually show that a meteorite impact was observed in which iron was subsequently found?
Were all the meteorites found identified as having fallen from the sky?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Actually, while we don't really have enough data to say for certain, the general consensus is that meteorites are *not* hot after landing, certainly not for a long time.

Comment: @DevSolar: There are conflicting reports; and while some report the meteorites as being even cool there are also known incidents of scarred grass around the landing. While the metallurgy is more complicated than I initially inferred, it seems certain that *enough* meteorites are warm to hot on landing as to verify their origin to observers.

Comment: As far as I understand, the word "bia" or "bja" ment not just iron, but any hard metal; so "metal of the sky" could be just a way to denote the exceptionality of iron compared to copper and bronze - as ironworking was not yet developed, Egyptians would be unlikely to make the distinction between meteoric iron and iron originating on Earth.